# Stuck in a gray screen after a fresh installation Kali Linux 2.0

Tags: boot, kali-linux

Today I just decided to install Kali Linux 2.0.

The installation finished successfully.

After that I tried to login but it only shows a grey screen after booting.

I don't know what's wrong with it.

What I've tried so far:

1. The <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> is working and the mouse is working.
2. I've tried to change `Automaticloginenable=true`.
3. I've tried to run in the GAU/Terminal:

   ```
   startx 
   update 
   upgrade
   ```

   but it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

I'v solved this problem by installing `lightdm`.

```
apt-get install lightdm
```

Then will ask you to choose `lightdm` or `gdm3`.

Choose `lightdm` and reboot.